# Error creating bean with name 'eventDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have been trying to find a solution to this issue for a while but cannot figure out the problem. I am trying to implement Fullcalendar using Spring MVC and hibernate but every time I run it I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'eventDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:
    private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.fyp.account.dao.EventDAOImpl.sessionFactory; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
    No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: 
    expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
    Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

The **EventDAOImpl.java** is the class where the error is originating from I believe:

```
package com.fyp.account.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.transform.Transformers;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.fyp.account.model.EventEntity;

@Repository("eventDAO")
public class EventDAOImpl implements EventDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<EventEntity> findAll() {
        List <EventEntity> list = null;
        Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session .beginTransaction();
            list = session.createQuery("select e.id as id, "
                    + "e.name as title, "
                    + "DATE_FORMAT(e.startDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as start, "
                    + "DATE_FORMAT(e.endDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as end "
                    + "from Event e")
                    .setResultTransformer(
                            Transformers.aliasToBean(EventEntity.class))
                    .list();
            transaction.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            list = null;
            if(transaction != null){
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

I will also put my **appconfig-data.xml** class below as I think the issue is partly to do with the mysql database connection.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Configure the data source bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.fyp.account.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable annotation driven transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!--
      Configure Spring Data JPA and set the base package of the
      repository interfaces
    -->

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.fyp.account.repository"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: I think you're mixing JPA and Hibernate initialization. EntityManagerFactory != SessionFactory

Comment: Any clue how to fix that issue? @Andreas

Comment: Read the Quick Start guides? E.g. https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/

Comment: Not sure how that helps @Andreas

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Hibernate directly (instead of JPA) and outdated approaches? Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA can replace your entire DAO and configuration.

Comment: No I have been trying to find examples of how to implement Fullcalendar and that is why I am using that. I am not sure how to go about replacing my entire DAO and configuration thats why I needed the examples @chrylis

Comment: You want the Spring Data project, most specifically Spring Data JPA, and the Getting Started guides (and the reference docs, which are quite good) are the place to look.